# ヘルプセンターの「質問がクローズ済みとは？」のレイアウトを改善したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [質問が [クローズ済み] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) において、クローズ理由の一覧とその説明が記載されていますが、文章のレイアウト = インデントに改善の余地があるんじゃないかと思います。

現状ではざっくりと以下のような構成になっていますが、(引用になっている)「テキスト例」や「補足説明」の部分を一段インデントして、理由の段落に収めたほうがより分かりやすくなる気がします。
特に「補足説明」の部分が現状だとどこにかかっている説明なのかが曖昧に見えます。

# [英語版のページ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) も現状では同じですが、無理に従う必要は無いのかなと。

---

クローズに関する全体的な説明

- **理由** - 説明

> クローズ時に表示されるテキスト例

補足説明

- **理由** - 説明

> クローズ時に表示されるテキスト例

補足説明

---

#### 実際の表示例

**現状:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**改善案:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 変更は軽微な内容なので、大きな反対が無ければ (下書きは用意せず) 直接ページを編集してしまおうと思っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

特に反対意見も出ていませんので、編集を反映しました。
(説明文等が箇条書きの内側に収まるように修正)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]